Struggling to Solve Discrete-Time LQR with Reinforcement Learning in Python
I’m working on solving a discrete-time LQR problem using reinforcement learning in Python. I’m using the Baselines library and creating my own environment. Initially, I tested a simple scalar example where A = B = Q = R = 1. My goal is to compare the learned policy u(x) to the optimal LQR solution by plotting control vs. state from -20 to 20.
I’m evaluating PPO, DDPG, and SAC algorithms. However, I’m finding it challenging to solve even this simple LQR problem with RL. The state distribution significantly affects the solutions, and I’m having trouble adjusting the termination conditions (step/reset functions) to achieve good convergence. Batch size and learning rate also seem to have a substantial impact.
I then moved to a multidimensional LQR problem with a two-dimensional state and a one-dimensional control. Here, controlling the state distribution to achieve convergence is even more difficult. PPO performs well only near the origin, and while DDPG works, it lacks good convergence.
My questions are:
Is it truly this challenging to replicate the LQR optimal solution using RL? Are there strategies or methods to ensure convergence regardless of system dimensions?
Has anyone successfully solved this problem and achieved good convergence? If so, which algorithms and parameters did you use?
I’m open to any suggestions or comments you may have. I also shared one of my Python codes (about 100-200 lines) if it helps.
Thank you!
import gymnasium as gym
import numpy as np
from stable_baselines3 import PPO, DDPG
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3.common.monitor import Monitor
from stable_baselines3.common.noise import NormalActionNoise
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
import seaborn as sns
import control as ctrl

# Define the scalar LTI system environment
class ScalarLTIEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, R=0.1, evaluate=False):
        super(ScalarLTIEnv, self).__init__()
        self.A = 1.0
        self.B = 1.0
        self.Q = 1.0
        self.R = R  # Control effort cost
        self.P = ctrl.dare(self.A, self.B, self.Q, self.R)[0]
        self.K, _, _ = ctrl.dlqr(self.A, self.B, self.Q, self.R)  # LQR gain
        self.evaluate = evaluate
        self.u_bound = 50.0
        
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Box(low=-self.u_bound, high=self.u_bound, shape=(1,), dtype=np.float32)
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(low=-np.inf, high=np.inf, shape=(1,), dtype=np.float32)
        
        self.state = np.zeros(1)
        self.steps = 0
        self.max_steps = 10
        self.state_history = [] 
    
    def reset(self, seed=None, options=None):
        if seed is not None:
            np.random.seed(seed)
        self.state = np.random.uniform(-3, 3, size=(1,))
        self.steps = 0
        return self.state.copy(), {}

    def step(self, action):
        u = np.clip(action, -self.u_bound, self.u_bound)[0]
        x_next = self.A * self.state + self.B * u
        self.state = x_next.flatten()
        
        # Store the state in history
        self.state_history.append(self.state.copy())
        
        # Compute the reward
        reward = -(self.Q * self.state**2 + self.R * u**2).item()
        
        self.steps += 1
        done = self.steps >= self.max_steps if not self.evaluate else False

        if done:
            reward -= self.P * self.state**2

        return self.state.copy(), reward, done, False, {}

    def render(self, mode='human'):
        pass
    
    def close(self):
        pass

# Initialize the environment
env = ScalarLTIEnv(R=1.0)
vec_env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: Monitor(env)])
# vec_env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])

# Set up PPO model
ppo_model = PPO('MlpPolicy', vec_env, verbose=0, learning_rate=0.001, gamma=0.9)

# Set up DDPG model with action noise
n_actions = env.action_space.shape[-1]
action_noise = NormalActionNoise(mean=np.zeros(n_actions), sigma=0.1 * np.ones(n_actions))
ddpg_model = DDPG('MlpPolicy', vec_env, action_noise=action_noise, verbose=0, gamma=0.9)

# Train both PPO and DDPG models
total_timesteps = 100000
batch_size = 1000
x_range = np.linspace(-20, 20, 100)

# Initialize arrays to store control actions
control_x_ppo = []
control_x_ddpg = []
control_x_lqr = []

# Train PPO model with progress tracking and live plotting every 10,000 steps
with tqdm(total=total_timesteps, desc="PPO Training Progress") as pbar:
    for step in range(0, total_timesteps, batch_size):
        ppo_model.learn(total_timesteps=batch_size, reset_num_timesteps=False)
        pbar.update(batch_size)
        
        if (step + batch_size) % 10000 == 0:
            control_x_ppo = []
            control_x_lqr = []
            for x in x_range:
                env.state = np.array([x])
                action_ppo, _ = ppo_model.predict(env.state, deterministic=True)
                control_x_ppo.append(action_ppo[0])
                u_lqr = -env.K * env.state
                control_x_lqr.append(u_lqr.flatten())  # Ensure LQR control is 1D

            plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
            plt.plot(x_range, control_x_ppo, label=f'PPO Control vs x at {step + batch_size} steps')
            plt.plot(x_range, control_x_lqr, label='LQR Control vs x', linestyle='--')
            plt.xlabel('x')
            plt.ylabel('Control')
            plt.title(f'Learned PPO Control vs LQR Control after {step + batch_size} steps')
            plt.grid(True)
            plt.legend()
            plt.show()


# Train DDPG model with progress tracking and live plotting every 10,000 steps
total_timesteps = 10000
batch_size = 1000
with tqdm(total=total_timesteps, desc="DDPG Training Progress") as pbar:
    for step in range(0, total_timesteps, batch_size):
        ddpg_model.learn(total_timesteps=batch_size, reset_num_timesteps=False)
        pbar.update(batch_size)
        
        if (step + batch_size) % 1000 == 0:
            control_x_ddpg = []
            control_x_lqr = []
            for x in x_range:
                env.state = np.array([x])
                action_ddpg, _ = ddpg_model.predict(env.state, deterministic=True)
                control_x_ddpg.append(action_ddpg[0])
                u_lqr = -env.K * env.state
                control_x_lqr.append(u_lqr.flatten()) 

            plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
            plt.plot(x_range, control_x_ddpg, label=f'DDPG Control vs x at {step + batch_size} steps')
            plt.plot(x_range, control_x_lqr, label='LQR Control vs x', linestyle='--')
            plt.xlabel('x')
            plt.ylabel('Control')
            plt.title(f'Learned DDPG Control vs LQR Control after {step + batch_size} steps')
            plt.grid(True)
            plt.legend()
            plt.show()

# Save models
ppo_model.save('ppo_scalar_lti_env')
ddpg_model.save('ddpg_scalar_lti_env')
print("Models saved.")

# Load the trained models
ppo_model = PPO.load('ppo_scalar_lti_env', env=vec_env)
ddpg_model = DDPG.load('ddpg_scalar_lti_env', env=vec_env)

# Define a grid for contour plotting
x_range = np.linspace(-20, 20, 100)
X = np.meshgrid(x_range)

# Initialize arrays to store the control actions and relative errors
control_ppo = np.zeros_like(X[0])
control_ddpg = np.zeros_like(X[0])
control_lqr = np.zeros_like(X[0])
relative_error_ppo = np.zeros_like(X[0])
relative_error_ddpg = np.zeros_like(X[0])

# Compute the control actions and relative errors over the grid
for i in range(X[0].shape[0]):
    state = np.array([X[0][i]])
    
    # PPO control action
    action_ppo, _ = ppo_model.predict(state, deterministic=True)
    control_ppo[i] = action_ppo
    
    # DDPG control action
    action_ddpg, _ = ddpg_model.predict(state, deterministic=True)
    control_ddpg[i] = action_ddpg
    
    # LQR control action
    control_lqr[i] = -env.K * state
    
    # Calculate relative errors
    relative_error_ppo[i] = np.abs((control_ppo[i] - control_lqr[i]) / control_lqr[i]) * 100
    relative_error_ddpg[i] = np.abs((control_ddpg[i] - control_lqr[i]) / control_lqr[i]) * 100

# Plot the control contours
plt.figure(figsize=(18, 6))

# PPO Control Contour
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.plot(x_range, control_ppo, label='PPO Control')
plt.plot(x_range, control_lqr, label='LQR Control', linestyle='--')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('Control')
plt.title('PPO Control vs LQR Control')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()

# DDPG Control Contour
plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.plot(x_range, control_ddpg, label='DDPG Control')
plt.plot(x_range, control_lqr, label='LQR Control', linestyle='--')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('Control')
plt.title('DDPG Control vs LQR Control')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Plot the relative error contours
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

# PPO Relative Error Contour
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(x_range, relative_error_ppo, label='PPO Relative Error (%)')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('Relative Error (%)')
plt.title('PPO Relative Error')
plt.grid(True)

# DDPG Relative Error Contour
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(x_range, relative_error_ddpg, label='DDPG Relative Error (%)')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('Relative Error (%)')
plt.title('DDPG Relative Error')
plt.grid(True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

